# Question in metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$. Let
$d(x,A) = \inf \{ d(x,a) \mid a \in A\}$.
If $d(x,A) = 0$ for all $x$ then which of the following must be true?

1. $A$ is compact
2. $A$ is closed
3. $A$ is dense
4. $A = X$

My attempt: Since if $A$ is dense in $X$, we can always find elements from $A$ that approximate a particular element in $X$. So I chose 3. But the book says 4. Can somebody tell me which is correct.

Comment: $X = [0, 1]$ and $A = [0, 1)$ cancel out the 1, 2 and 4 :)

Comment: Very simple and yet elegant!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, and a non-empty bounded subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$, we have \begin{align}
\alpha = \inf B & \iff \textrm{for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\alpha+\varepsilon$ is not a lower bound of $B$} \\ & \iff \textrm{for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $b_\varepsilon \in B$ such that $b_\varepsilon<\alpha+\varepsilon$.}
\end{align}
In your case, $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $a_\varepsilon \in A$ such that $d(x,a_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$, which means, $d(x,A)=0$ if and only if for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Thus, $d(x,A)=0$ is equivalent to $x \in \overline A$.